# Sign in with Facebook, Firebase is changing UID when signing in the second time, Kotlin Android Studio

Tags: android, facebook, firebase, kotlin

I want to sign in automatically when I load the activity if it was logged in before and not logged out, but when I create a new user, after commenting out the on start check if user is signed in part, it crashes. Also I can create a user with Facebook login and go to the next activity but when I sign out and sign back in with the Facebook button it creates a new UID which I don't want. I want it to recognize that there is already a user signed up with that Facebook. I am new to Kotlin I normally use iOS and Swift and can do this in that.

```
public override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()

    // Check if user is signed in (non-null) and update UI accordingly.
    val currentUser = auth.currentUser
    progressBar.visibility = View.INVISIBLE

    if (auth.currentUser == null) {
        println("Tony signed out")
    }else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Already Signed in :)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        println("Tony signed in")
        userID = auth?.currentUser?.uid!!
        val intent = Intent(this, ProjectsVC::class.java)
        progressBar.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        startActivity(Intent(this, ProjectsVC::class.java))
    }

}
```

My Button

```
facebookLogin.setOnClickListener {
        LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("public_profile"))
        progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        facebookLogin()
    }
```

Facebook Function

```
private fun facebookLogin() {

    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create()


    LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, object : FacebookCallback<LoginResult> {

        override fun onSuccess(loginResult: LoginResult) {

            Log.d("Main", "facebook:onSuccess:$loginResult")

            handleFacebookAccessToken(loginResult.accessToken)
        }
```

Handle Token

```
private fun handleFacebookAccessToken(token: AccessToken) {
    progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    Log.d("Main", "handleFacebookAccessToken:$token")
    println("Tony started facebook login")

    val credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(token.token)

    auth.signInWithCredential(credential)
        .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful) {
                println("Tony task Facebook login")
                // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                Log.d("Main", "signInWithCredential:success")

                usernameCheck {success ->
                    if (success == true) {
                        if (userExist) {
                            println("Tony User exists")
                            progressBar.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                        }else {
                            println("Tony User doesn't exist")
                            val mAlertDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this@LogInVC)
                            mAlertDialog.setTitle("Enter a Username")
                            mAlertDialog.setMessage("This will allow you to be added to other projects")
                            val view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_verify_vc, null)
                            view.codeVerify.hint = "Username"
                            view.codeVerify.inputType = InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_WORDS
                            mAlertDialog.setView(view)
                            mAlertDialog.setPositiveButton("Ok") { dialog: DialogInterface?, id: Int ->
                                userName = view.codeVerify.text.toString()
                                progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                                val post = HashMap<String, Any>()
                                post["username"] = userName

                                db.collection ("users").document(userID)
                                    .set(post)
                                    .addOnSuccessListener { Log.d("UserCheck2", "Tony DocumentSnapshot successfully written!") }
                                    .addOnFailureListener { e -> Log.w("UserCheck2", " Tony Error writing document", e) }
                                    println("Tony db check uid is $userID and username $userName")
                                checkNameExists { success ->
                                    if (success) {
                                        if (userNameExist) {
                                            println("Tony Username used")
                                           // create alert that has a check function and write function on ok


                                            }else {
                                            println("Tony Username not used")
                                            val post2 = HashMap<String, Any>()
                                            post2["UserID"] = userID
                                            db.collection("usernames").document(userName)
                                                .set(post2)
                                                .addOnSuccessListener { Log.d("UserCheck", "Tony DocumentSnapshot successfully written!")
                                                    val intent = Intent(this, ProjectsVC::class.java)
                                                    progressBar.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                                                    startActivity(intent)
                                                }
                                                .addOnFailureListener { e -> Log.w("UserCheck", "Tony Error writing document", e) }

                                        }
                                    }else {
                                        println("Tony Error")
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            mAlertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel") { dialog: DialogInterface?, id: Int ->
                                dialog?.dismiss()
                            }
                            progressBar.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                            mAlertDialog.show()
                        }
                    }else {
                    println("Tony not success")
                        progressBar.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                }
                }
                println("Tony Finished facebook login")
            } else {
                // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                Log.w("Main", "signInWithCredential:failure", task.exception)
                Toast.makeText(
                    baseContext, "Authentication failed.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show()
                progressBar.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            }

        }
}
```

on the handle Facebook token if a user has already registered then I don't want it to go to the username check.

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.

Comment: Thank you for your Time on this Alex I was able to solve this, it was crashing because I was calling to set the uid too early and it had nul and l was force unwrapping it. by setting it to get the uid later it solved the issue

Comment: Good to hear that, cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this by not calling to set my uid for the user in the on create, but to set it once I had hit the login and recived a success on that instead.